# wijgrid object not supported

Tags: javascript, asp.net, wijmo

I have an asp.net project which consists of a master page and content pages. One of my content pages has a table on it called `table1`. I am trying to configure a grid in JavaScript but receive the error:

```
JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'wijgrid'
```

The line of code referenced by the error is located within the `pageLoad` function. The exact line looks like this:

`$("#table1").wijgrid();`

I created a blank web page with similar code that works. Can anyone shed any light on why this is not working?

```
<asp:Table ID="table1" runat="server">
</asp:Table>
```

This is my code which attempts to design and populate the grid:

```js
<asp:Table ID="table1" runat="server">
                </asp:Table>

$.ajax({
        type: "post",
        async: false,
        url: "CICBatchTransfer.aspx/GetCICs",
        data: "{'sNavCode':'" + $('#drpSiteSource').val() + "','sAreaCode':'" + $("#drpAreaSource").val() + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (r) {
            cicdata = r.d;
            cicdata = jQuery.parseJSON(cicdata)
            $("#grdCICs").wijgrid({
                showFilter: true,
                allowPaging: false,
                ensureColumnsPxWidth: true,
                scrollMode: "vertical",
                data: cicdata,
                columnsAutogenerationMode: "none",
                columns: [
                        { dataKey: "CI_REFNO", headerText: "CI_REFNO", dataType: "number", visible: false },
                        { dataKey: "CI_REFERENCE", headerText: "Reference", dataType: "string", width: 115 },
                        { dataKey: "CI_DESCRIPTION", headerText: "Description", dataType: "string", width: 370 }
                    ]
            });
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert('GetCICs - ' + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });​
```

Comment: Please add your code, your question is not clear.

Comment: The error is Object doesn't support property or method 'wijgrid' when doing the $("#grdCICs").wijgrid